# Can someone tell me what i did wrong here discord.py dming system

Tags: python, discord.py

I was was trying to get it to dm the user who used the command but it doesn't seem to work can someone explain what i did wrong?

````py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        channel = client.get_channel(942903733262626836)
        await channel.send(f"{message.author} sent:\n```{message.content}```")
    await client.process_commands(message)

@client.command()
async def feedback(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message='Hello please let us know about your about your feedback.'):
    message = message
    await user.send(message)
    await ctx.send('DM Sent Succesfully.')
````

Answer (score 0):

If `feedback` is a command that the user has to write (ex. !feedback) then you can just use `ctx.author.send()` which will send the dm to the author of the command. What are you trying to do with the `on_message` function?

```
@client.command()
async def feedback(ctx, message='Hello please let us know about your about your feedback.'):
    await ctx.author.send(message)
    await ctx.send('DM Sent Succesfully.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You made `user` an argument to the command & you're DMing *that person* instead of the author.

```py
async def command(ctx, user: discord.User, ...)
```

must be used as

```
!command @user
```

where `@user` pings the user **that will be DM'ed**.

You said you wanted to DM the person that used the command, which is the author, so you should DM them instead. You can access the author using `ctx.author`, and DM them the same way you just DM'ed the other user.

```py
# Instead of
await user.send(...)
# use
await ctx.author.send(...)
```